# JupyterHub - install or upgrade notebook to v7

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

Using automatic script to install JupyterHub: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jupyterhub/the-littlest-jupyterhub/master/bootstrap/bootstrap.py

After installation I check: `sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/jupyterhub.service` and found run path:

```
ExecStart=/opt/tljh/hub/bin/python3 -m jupyterhub.app -f /opt/tljh/hub/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tljh/jupyterhub_config.py --upgrade-db
```

Then install new version of notebook with pip:

```
/opt/tljh/hub/bin/python3 -m pip install notebook
```

Now:

```
$ /opt/tljh/hub/bin/python3 -m notebook -V
7.0.0
```

After restart jupyterhub service and creating new notebook i still see in Help **notebook server is 6**:

[image: About Jupyter Notebook]

How to upgrade notebooks to 7 version?